# При удалении свайпом последнего элемента удаляется первый

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-room, itemtouchhelper

Помогите пожалуйста, ни как не могу понять в чем дело.
При удалении последнего элемента свайпом(ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback) удаляется первый элемент. Так происходит только с последним элементом. Все остальное работает удаляется без проблем

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NotesAdapter notesAdapter;
private AlertDialog dialogURL;
private static ArrayList<Note> notesFromDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ...


RecyclerView recyclerViewNotes = findViewById(R.id.rv_notes);
    recyclerViewNotes.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    notesFromDB = new ArrayList<>();
    notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter();

    MainViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getNotes().observe(this, notes -> {
        notesFromDB = (ArrayList<Note>) notes;
        notesAdapter.setItems(notesFromDB);
    });

    new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewNotes);
    recyclerViewNotes.setAdapter(notesAdapter); ...

private final ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback =
        new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                  @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                                  @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                App.getInstance().getNoteDao().deleteNote(notesFromDB.get(position));
                notesAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

            }
        };
```

Мой адаптер

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder> {

private final SortedList<Note> sortedList;

public NotesAdapter() {
    sortedList = new SortedList<>(Note.class, new SortedList.Callback<Note>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Note o1, Note o2) {
            if (!o2.isDone() && o1.isDone()) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (o2.isDone() && !o1.isDone()) {
                return -1;
            }
            return (int) (o2.timestamp - o1.timestamp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(Note oldItem, Note newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        } ...

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sortedList.size();
}

public void setItems(List<Note> notes) {
    sortedList.replaceAll(notes);
} ...
```

Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался!
Добавил в адаптер:

```
public Note getNoteAt(int position){
    return sortedList.get(position);
}
```

При свайпе:

```
@Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            App.getInstance().getNoteDao().deleteNote(notesAdapter.getNoteAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));

        }...
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте добавить в свой адаптер

```
 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {    
 return position;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]